# How can I return a value in a select based on the value of another field?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this select:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[get_tests] @UserTestId INT
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    SELECT  A.CompletedDate,       
        A.ID,            
        Current     -- need to set this field to a 1 or 0               
        A.UserTestId,  
        ...
```

There is no field called `Current` in the table but I would like to have a field that will be set to 1 if `A.UserTestId = @UserTestId`.

Can someone show me how I can do this?

Comment: `Current = CASE WHEN A.UserTestId = @UserTestId THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use a `CASE` expression to evaluate another field in the select clause.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[get_tests] @UserTestId INT
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    SELECT  A.CompletedDate,       
        A.ID,            
        CASE A.UserTestId WHEN @UserTestId THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Current,
   A.UserTestId,
```